# match_phrase doesn't work well with Synonym Token Filter (genre expansion) in Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

**UPDATE**:

The issue seems to have been fixed after reading Richa's explanation and the recommended [blog post](http://bitsandbites.me/blog/2014/04/08/elasticsearch-synonyms/), but I need more testings before I can confirm.

First, the synonym format should be changed as suggested by Richa:

["green => khaki,green", "pet => cat,pet"]

Then, I have to specify the `search_analyzer` and `index_analyzer` in the index mapping:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "phone_case": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false,
        "index_analyzer": "standard",
        "search_analyzer": "lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
```

After adding those two properties in the mapping, I do not need to use `analyzer` in queries.

These changes seem to make genre expansion work as expected in either "term" and "match_phrase" queries.

---

Elasticsearch 7.2

Synonym data:

`[ "khaki => khaki,green", "cat => cat,pet"]`

Index mapping:

```
{
    settings: {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "same_word": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": ["-=>", "&=>and"]
                },
            },
            "filter": {
                "my_stopwords": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": STOPWORD_FILE
                },
                "my_synonym": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms": [ "khaki => khaki,green", "cat => cat,pet"],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                },
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": ["html_strip", "same_word"],
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_stopwords",
                        "my_synonym",
                    ]
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Material field:

```
"phone_case":{"type":"text","norms":false,"analyzer":"lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer"}
```

Example documents:

```
 [
  {
      id: "1",
      phone_case: "khaki,brushed and polished",
  },
  {
      id: "2",
      phone_case: "green,brushed",
  },
  {
      id: "3",
      phone_case: "black,matte"
  }
]
```

The "phone_case" field is a text field.

When I search for **khaki** I want to find documents with just **khaki** results, excluding any results that contain **green**. On the other hand, when searching for **green**, I want to get documents with either **green** or **khaki**. That should be what Genre Expansion is supposed to do.

The term level query works fine for such purposes:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "updated": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "phone_case": "khaki"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It manages to return documents containing **khaki**.

But with **match_phrase**, it returns documents with either **khaki** or **green**. That isn't what I expected. I want to get documents that contain **khaki**, not **green**:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "updated": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "phone_case": "khaki"
    }
  }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the **match** query not able to exclude results that contain "green"? I want to allow uses to look up the text field in exact order but **match** or **match_phrase** doesn't work well with Genre Expansion Synonyms.

Comment: Please share the mapping of your index and a sample document

Comment: @Richa Hello, I've just included the mapping and sample documents.

Comment: In the description you have `When I search for "ceramic" I want to find documents with just "ceramic" results. When searching for "ceramic", I want to get documents with either "ceramic" or "cerachrom".` . I think , the second time it is `cerachrom`

Comment: @Richa, thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I just changed the example to make it easier to understand and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#_solr_synonyms), when we define our synonyms like `a => b,c`, that is resolved as

```
# Explicit mappings match any token sequence on the LHS of "=>"
# and replace with all alternatives on the RHS.  These types of mappings
# ignore the expand parameter in the schema.
```

So for your case, `"khaki => khaki,green"`, The word `khaki` would be replaced with `khaki` and `green`. This can be seen using `analyze` api like

```
GET stack-57703209/_analyze
{
  "text": "khaki",
  "analyzer": "lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer"
}
```

This returns two token, `khaki` and `green`.

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "khaki",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "green",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

and if you check it for `green`

```
GET stack-57703209/_analyze
{
  "text": "green",
  "analyzer": "lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer"
}
```

You will get only one token `green`.

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "green",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

As per your question, you want the opposite, So ideally the synonym should look like below

```
"green => khaki,green"
 not "khaki => khaki,green"
```

In addition to that, you are applying this analyzer at `index` time. So while indexing your document, The word `khaki` is replaced by `khaki` and `green` tokens as we saw above using analyse api.

When you run `Term Query`, which searches for exact term

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "updated": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "phone_case": "khaki"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you search for `khaki`, you get only first result in response as Term Query does not apply any search analyzer and matches the exact term, So it looks for `khaki` and second document which is `phone_case: "green,brushed",` has no token with `khaki` (can be checked using analyze api) and therefore is not returned.

But, [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#match-field-params), applies the analyzer which is same as `index analyzer` by default and in your case `lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer`. So both the documents are returned.

So for your requirement, you would need a `search analyzer` and not an `index analyzer`, So you can change your index setting to

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "same_word": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "-=>",
            "&=>and"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stopwords": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "a, an"
        },
        "my_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "green => khaki,green",      //NOTE THIS
            "cat => cat,pet"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip",
            "same_word"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_stopwords"
            ]
        },
        "synonym_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "my_synonym"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "phone_case": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false,
        "analyzer": "lowercaseWhiteSpaceAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then specify the `search analyzer` instead, like

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "phone_case" : {
                "query" : "green",
                "analyzer" : "synonym_analyzer"  // NOTE THIS

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This](http://bitsandbites.me/blog/2014/04/08/elasticsearch-synonyms/) blog explains this in a bit more details.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It helps a lot. But in order to get genre expansion  work as expected, I have to specify the `index_analyzer` and `search_analyzer` in the index mapping. With them added, I do not need to use `analyzer` in `match_phrase` queries . Please check my updated post to see if there are any things left out.

Comment: @RedGiant Yeah..  `Search Anlayzer` can be specified in the settings as well.

Comment: With multi-word synonyms, like `"vintage inspired => vintage inspired,reissue,retro"`  I have to use **synonym_graph** instead of **synonym** to get it to work in "match" queries. I wonder if it is necessary, as I found an example about `sea biscuit, sea biscit => seabiscuit` in the documentation for "synonym token filter" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Yeah. For multiwords, you should go for `synonym_graph`